# Fetch ROWID from table and store it in array

Tags: sql, plsql

I like to fetch 100 records from a table and fetch the ROWID of same records and store it in an array. Then I like to take rowid of the 1st record and do some processing.

Could you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I would firstly ask - why on earth would you need ROWIDs stored in a table? Those references change and if you like to have them for some reason, I suggest you to create a view which selects them for your needs. I imagine a situation like so: You store the ROWID of a row in that custom table and then, after a set period of time the DB rearanges those rowids (or a separate procedure does it) and you're no longer able to distinguish this change and you SELECTs would return other rows (if you don't have any triggers to handle this change).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of type ROWID and then write a SELECT query to get those rowids into the array. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_rowids IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  vt_rowids t_rowids;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID ROW_ID
  BULK COLLECT INTO vt_rowids
  FROM table t
  WHERE your_conditions...
  AND ROWNUM <= 100; -- if you just want 100 records

  FOR i IN vt_rowids.first()..vt_rowids.last() LOOP
    -- Do your processing here...
    dbms_output.put_line('rowid: ' || vt_rowids(i));
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```